# How to find per-tab internet usage in Firefox?

Tags: linux, networking, firefox, browser-tabs

Sometimes I'm on a slow internet connection, and Firefox is using up all my bandwidth. I can track per-process bandwidth usage with a program like nethogs. However, if I've got multiple tabs open, I have no idea which one of them is generating the traffic, and killing the process (Firefox) obviously kills all of my tabs.

Is there a simple way to track per-tab bandwidth-usage? I just want to be able to kill the tabs that are generating traffic in the background.

I'm on Linux (Debian) in case there are any system-specific solutions.

Comment: The best approach here is to close tabs as you finish that particular page.  This will keep it from updating and also reduce memory usage.

Comment: I wasn't able to find any addons that can keep track of this. Looks like `about:networking` doesn't break things down by tab either. Sorry!